# Search a column against each member of another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I would like to search a column in a table against each member of another column and print the results.  I wrote a for-loop in PHP but it is too intensive as it involves too many queries.  I’m open to using any web-enabled language.

```
$search1=mysql_query(SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE %Search_term%);
    for($i=0; i < $search1->num_rows; $i++){
        $search2=mysql_query(SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE %Seach_term% AND COLUMN1 LIKE “%$search1[$i]%” LIMIT 3);
        echo “$search2[0]”;
        echo “$search2[1]”;
        echo “$search2[2]”;
        echo “<P>”;
        $i++;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without doing a select statement every instance of the for loop?  If I could select it once and then loop through in SQL and sort or group it, I’d be so happy.  I looked into GROUPBY or SORTBY but I couldn’t find an example close of to this to apply it to this.

Thank you.

```
    edit: example table

    id        column1                        column2
    1         walk park dog win for good     walk
    2         walk go forward do win dog     go
    3         park job forward daycare a     park 
    4         go with me certified job I     with
    5         dolphin job park walk care     dolphin
    6         pack for good park go job      for
    7         leader forward win dog for     leader
    8         leader go forward win walk     forward
    9         tablet forward go walk for     tablet
    10        Jones job me certfied do go    job


results of searching by column2 into column1:

walk go forward do win dog
dolphin job park walk care
leader go forward win walk

walk go forward do win dog
go with me certified job I
pack for good park go job

walk park dog win for good
park job forward daycare a
dolphin job park walk care

go with me certified job I

dolphin job park walk care

walk park dog win for good
leader forward win dog for
tablet forward go walk for

leader forward win dog for
leader go forward win walk

walk go forward do win dog
park job forward daycare a
leader forward win dog for

tablet forward go walk for

park job forward daycare a
go with me certified job I
dolphin job park walk care
```

--

The actual table is 25,000,000 literature citations and the second column is the same citations with common stop words taken out.  The dream is to group common citations together.

Thank you again.

Comment: Can you please give us more details of the tables involved and exactly how the data links between them?

Comment: I just provided a sample table and an explanation of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a start - especially as you have 25,000,000 records in your table...
Your PHP seems to grab a word from the second column and to return just three random hits from the first column. This limiting down to three hits does neither of the following do, yet.

Just any hit - including, e.g., "walk park dog win for good" for "go", and "leader go forward win walk" for "for":

```
SELECT
  c2.column2
  , c1.column1
  , c1.id
FROM citation c1
JOIN citation c2
  ON INSTR(c1.column1, c2.column2)
ORDER BY c2.column2, c1.column1
;
```

A bit more selective - limiting the matches to full words:

```
SELECT
  c2.column2
  , c1.column1
  , c1.id
FROM citation c1
JOIN citation c2
  ON FIND_IN_SET(c2.column2, REPLACE(c1.column1, ' ', ','))
ORDER BY c2.column2, c1.column1
;
```

This way, however, even simple plurals (formed by adding just an "s") are no longer caught - compare the added eleventh record, which is returned for "dolphins" but no longer for "dolphin" in the second query in below SQL Fiddle.

See it in  action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e27ef/1)

This, certainly, needs tuning / more detailed requirements.

Personally, I don't see, how "the second column is the same citations with common stop words taken out" - as I find just single words in that column.
I'd, perhaps, start with something along a table with just (pre-processed) citations (which reference the originals), and a word list, which includes the words' derived forms. (Alternatively, the citation pre-processing could take care of this aspect.) A simple SQL would, of course, not address the difference between the noun "walk" and the verb "walk". Including that in the output as in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fc6f/2) would just be a reminder to the person, working on it - if this is at all relevant in your context.

Depending on your actual (overall) requirements, it might be worth to look into [MySQL's full text functionalities](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.